# How to get flink streaming jar to kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, flink-streaming

With maven am building a fat jar for my streaming app. Have to deploy the jar to a k8 cluster. Enterprise don't have internal docker hub. So my option is to build the image as part of jenkins and use the same in kub job manager config. I would appreciate if any example demonstrating the project layout and steps to deploy

Used the build.sh script from https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/docker/README.md and able to convert to docker image. And using docker compose am able to get the app running. But when trying for kub as specified in https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/kubernetes/README.md#deploy-flink-job-cluster am seeing image not found.

Comment: Have you uploaded your image to an repository? Also can you share your deployment .yaml file?

Comment: I dont have a repository in the enterprise to store the image. So wanted to know if there is a way to directly deploy fat jar files

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not manage images, it relies on Docker for that. You can check the Docker documentation [About images, containers, and storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/).

In Kubernetes You can use the following registries: [Google Container Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-google-container-registry), [AWS EC2 Container Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-aws-ec2-container-registry), [Azure Container Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-azure-container-registry-acr), [IBM Cloud Container Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-ibm-cloud-container-registry) and your own [Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry)

You can read the Kubernetes documentation on how to [Pull an Image from a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

You can find many projects helping with the setup of your own private registry.
One of the easiest ones is the project [k8s-local-docker-registry](https://github.com/SeldonIO/k8s-local-docker-registry) by [SeldonIO](https://github.com/SeldonIO).

Start/Stop private registry in cluster

> **start private registry**
>   `./start-docker-private-registry`
>
> **stop private registry**
>   `./stop-docker-private-registry`
>
> Check if the registry catalog can be accessed and the ability to push an image.
>   `(set -x && curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2/_catalog && docker pull busybox && docker tag busybox 127.0.0.1:5000/busybox && docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/busybox)`

Comment: Thank you for the great insight. I will try the proposed solution